# How to access Blockchain remotely for statistics study?

Tags: blockchain, api, block, synchronization

I would like to write small paper supported by Blockchain stats.
Could you tell me how to access blocks chain remotely via GUI to make a query ?

Blockchain's size is 159GB as of today, so download is heavy.

Ok, I can study block headers only to limit overheads.

Do you know how to download or access blockchain headers as mySQL database ?

How to access Blockchain remotely for statistics study ?

Comment: Ok, I can limit my interest to block headers only to create  database. 
 
https://blockchain.info/block-height/474044?format=json  So all I need is block header from the above block. Any download link ? Studied blockchain json API but no support for block header only.

Comment: https://blockchain.info/block-height/491459  is the answer but output is not generated via API, so I need raw json block header output, not full webpage code included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention in your comments, blockchain.info can provide this information.

You can get a raw block in JSON format using the /rawblock/ links, for example:
https://blockchain.info/rawblock/0000000000000000008d49f25f7dd5d3704575a348e030a1d2e5f396b3e80516

Then you can also get it as the hex-encoded raw block by adding `?format=hex` to the url:
https://blockchain.info/rawblock/0000000000000000008d49f25f7dd5d3704575a348e030a1d2e5f396b3e80516?format=hex

Hope that's what you are after :)

EDIT: Oh, just re-read your comment, you want *just* the headers? In that case you probably can't use blockchain.info, you could try BlockCyhper instead:

For example: https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/blocks/294322

You can find more info about their API here: https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#blockchain-api

Comment: thank you MeshCollider for your excellent answer.  At first view block headers by blockcypher and by blockchain look the same but blockcypher sets nonce to "0" . I have no tools to verify if other data in the block header are reliable generate charts for my paper   Just have a look: https://blockchain.info/block-height/491658  vs.  https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/blocks/491658 or https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/blocks/294322 nonce always set to "0" so what you get is not valid blopck header